# How can I dynamically add actions to a QMenu while it is open on a Mac?

Tags: macos, qt, pyside, qmenu

I have `QSystemTrayIcon` with a `QMenu`. In order to fill the menu, I need to fetch some things from the network, so I want to do that in the background.

So I have a `QThread` with a slot that is connected to the `activated` signal of the tray icon. Then the thread fetches the resources and updates the menu using another signal.

However, these updates do not show until I close and reopen the menu.

This seems to be a Mac specific problem. I ran my code on Windows, and there it updated more or less correctly. Is there any workaround?

Below is an extracted version of the problem. When the menu is opened, it will sleep 1 second in a thread and then change the menu. This change is not seen.

```
import sys
import time
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class PeerMenu(QtGui.QMenu):

    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMenu.__init__(self)
        self.set_peers("prestine")

    @QtCore.Slot(object)
    def set_peers(self, label):
        self.clear()

        self.addAction(QtGui.QAction(label, self))
        self.addSeparator()
        self.addAction(QtGui.QAction("Hello", self))

class GUIListener(QtCore.QObject):

    files = QtCore.Signal(object)

    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self)
        self.counter = 0

    @QtCore.Slot()
    def check(self):
        time.sleep(1)
        self.counter += 1
        self.files.emit(str(self.counter))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    icon = QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon(QtGui.QIcon('images/glyphicons-206-electricity.png'), app)

    listener = GUIListener()
    t = QtCore.QThread()
    t.start()
    listener.moveToThread(t)

    menu = PeerMenu()
    icon.activated.connect(listener.check)
    listener.files.connect(menu.set_peers)

    icon.setContextMenu(menu)

    icon.show()

    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Why don't you do all the stuff in the slot connected to the `QMenu::aboutToShow()` signal of the context menu?

Comment: That would still block the menu, right? In this example it would take 1 second to show the menu. In real life, the network might be broken and the menu will never show.

Comment: Well, but why do you use menu for showing something that is not yet available? User will need to open the menu and wait without clicking elsewhere to keep the menu opened until the data got fetched?

Comment: Well yea. Usually the data is there within half a second. But maybe I should look into using a window like Dropbox does.

Comment: Yeah, IMO, using a window or dialog would make user experience better.

Comment: If you know how to make a popup similar to Dropbox, I'll gladly accept that as an answer. https://d339l1rkauam1y.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/mac.png

Comment: And you can't force redrawing ?

Comment: I tried both update() and repaint() but no change. Note that it works on Windows. It seems a Mac menu is just fixed as soon as it's open, so another workaround is needed. Maybe a small dialog or QWidgetAction, but I'm unsuccessful so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a few hours of extensive googling I finally figured it out.

You can create a borderless window using `QtGui.QMainWindow(parent=None, flags=QtCore.Qt.Popup)` and then find the location of the icon with `icon.geometry().center()` and finally move the window there with `window.move(icon_point)`.

There is some hackery involved in deciding how to place the window relative to the icon. Full code can be found at https://github.com/pepijndevos/gierzwaluw/blob/master/gui.py

Comment: The link does not work. And the answer does not really fit the question, since it does not talk about menus.

Comment: It does not seem to be possible, so this appears to be the only workaround.

Comment: Ah okay. Could you then maybe create a small example how it's done with a window and add it here, since the link doesn't work.